# Mysql - table name inparameter to stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Ok, so here's what I try. I can execute this code without problems:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`dbname`@`%.domain.com` PROCEDURE `test4`(_sort character(2), 
_start int, _page int, _seek varchar(64))

begin
    select * from TABLE_OF_NAMES where

        first_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), first_name) or
        last_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), last_name)   
        and email in (select * from TempTable_emails)

   order by

        case when _sort = 'fa' then first_name end asc,
        case when _sort = 'fd' then first_name end desc,
    limit _start, _page;
end
```

Now I want the name of the table TempTable_emails should be an parameter to the procedure. I try the following:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`dbname`@`%.domain.com` PROCEDURE `test4`(_sort character(2),
 _start int, _page int, _seek varchar(64),  _tablename varchar(64))
    begin

  set @a = concat(' select * from TABLE_OF_NAMES where
    first_name like coalesce(%', _seek, '%), first_name) or
    last_name like coalesce(%', _seek, '%), last_name)  and
    email in (select * from ',_tablename,')
    order by
    case when \'',_sort,'\' = \'fa\' then first_name end asc,
    case when \'',_sort,'\' = \'fd\' then first_name end desc,
    limit _start, _page;');

prepare stmt1 FROM @a;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
end
```

This however only produces the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%gauss%), first_name) or  last_name like coalesce(%NAME%), last_name) and ' at line 2"

I feel like I probably should see what the error is, but I just can't get it to work... does anyone see straight away what my error is?

Is there another (maybe easier) workaround for what I want to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
like coalesce(%', _seek, '%), first_name)
```

will not result in

```
like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), first_name)
```

It will result in something like;

```
like coalesce(%gauss%), first_name)
```

which, without quotes surrounding `%gauss%` is not valid SQL, and you seem to have lost the `concat` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change 
 
first_name like coalesce(%', _seek, '%), first_name)

to
   
first_name like coalesce(concat(\'%\',_seek, \'%\'), first_name)
 
This however produces the error "unknown column '_seek' in 'where clause. 
   
I thought the latter would result in    
   
first_name like coalesce(concat('%',_seek, '%'), first_name)
   
Which is what I have in the first (working) version.
   
Thanks,
Niklas

Comment: I think what you want is `... coalesce(concat(\'%',_seek, '%\') ...`

Comment: Ok, I had a typo in my code. Your answer solved my main problem, I just mistyped it when re-writing the code... Thank you!